# Apache proxy gzip

Tags: apache, proxy, gzip

I am using Apache 2.4 as a proxy server. All requests that have `myapp` are being redirected to tomcat that serves files. I am using `mod_proxy.so`(proxy) and `mod_deflate.so` (gzip). In my httpd.config (Apache config) this is what I have:

```
ProxyPass /myapp/ http://myserver:58080/myapp/
<Location /fusebox/>
        ProxyPassReverse /myapp/
        RequestHeader   unset   Accept-Encoding
        #SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
</Location>
```

Do you have any suggestions why this is not working?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the short answer, but I'm just passing by in a hurry.

Your proxypass-directive is likely working og Apache is likely serving out content from your Tomcat (if your Tomcat is healthy).

Your proxypassreverse-directive, requestheader and outputfilter are unlikely to be doing anything since they are contained in a location-directive not related to your proxypass. Loose the location-tags and things are going to happen.

Kind regards,
Helge